# How to receive youtube notifications with another account

Tags: youtube, notifications

I have a public youtube account that I use to upload stuff related to my multimedia work, but I also have a personal account.
I don't use or login too often to my public account, so I would love to receive it's notifications (comments and subscribtions) into my personal account.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK YouTube doesn't have such feature (tell me if I'm wrong). And I would not recomend using 3rd party software (if exist) as writing login and password into another program is always risky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally just use google's multi sign in feature which allows me to swap between YouTube accounts with breeze however here is a link I found from google that might help. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3523594?hl=en

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Asked, answered and accepted in less than 30 minutes. That's why we love SuperUser. Would deserve +1 if you included the key points from the linked content. As per the [guidelines](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DavidPostill is too fast for me...

Comment: @Kristian I have 50 or so comments ready to paste ;) Have you seen [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116)?